# Stop all symbols being changed to mathbb after specifying \mathbb

Tags: amsmath, amsfonts

When using [this format](http://www.jcss.gr.jp/CFPs/jcss.sty), I encountered very interesting phenomena, where `\mathbb` mode does not stop even after putting "}".

By compiling the following,

```
\documentstyle[amsfonts]{jcss}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{R}D$ % Please note that putting "}" before "D"
\end{document}
```

I got

[image]

although the below should be rendered:

[image]

Do you know why? Is it possible to fix this?

Maybe the above TeX document will raise an error. If so, please use this [TeX file](http://www.jcss.gr.jp/CFPs/guide-and-sample.tex) and add `$\mathbb{R}D$` to the TeX file.

Comment: Why are you using that format? `\documentstyle`?

Comment: Thank you, guys... I already struggled with using LaTeX2e with jcss style but unfortunately I could not. I don't know why they still use LaTeX2.09...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTeX2e has many improvements, for example: font selection and stuff. Here, with ancient LaTeX 2.09, `\mathbb` is rather a font switch than a command with argument. A group is needed to limit its scope:

```
\documentstyle[amsfonts]{article}
\begin{document}
$\begingroup\mathbb{R}\endgroup D$
${\mathbb{R}}D$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\begingroup` and `\endgroup` is longer for writing, but free of side effects. Curly braces and `\bgroup`/`\egroup` also act as math subformula, which can change the horizontal spacing around symbols. But here, the letter is a `\mathord` anyway, thus curly braces are fine here, too.

Consider switching to LaTeX2e, if the document class/style `jcss` allows this.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use `jcss` style file by putting `\documentclass{jcss}` but `! Font \fivedm=dm5 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found` error occurred...

Comment: @rkjt50r983 I could not test with `jcss`, because there where some character errors in the downloaded style file and no time to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

From the header of the file `amsfonts.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
```

This package is not intended to be backward compatible with LaTeX2e formats prior to 1994/12/01. By implication, it is not meant to be compatible with LaTeX2.09, the format that became deprecated in 1994 but which is loaded (in emulation mode) by the first line of your code, viz.,

```
\documentstyle[...]{jcss}
```